# Drupal Expressa theme issue in store page product listing designing

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, themes, view, multilingual

I am using Expressa theme and facing a problem into Store page product listing designing.

My site is multilingual.

I have attached two screenshot of store page product listing, one for when i am in default language and another for after change language, just see the selected 
red marked area into the both screenshot.

When i am in default language then the product listing showing fine

[image]

But when i change the language from default (English) to Danish then the product listing in store page not showing as same as default language.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of `expressa` theme's `template.php` setting. Into template.php file of expressa theme:

```
function expressa_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if (request_path() == 'store') {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__store';
}
```

For `request_path() == 'store'` condition the `node__store` template never call when the path will changed to `da/store`.

So for this just see the below code:

```
function expressa_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  global $language ;
  $lang_name = $language->language;   //For current language 
  if ($lang_name && request_path() == $lang_name.'/store') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__store';
  } else if (request_path() == 'store') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__store';
  }
}
```

This code will help you.